# Display Color name instead of color hex in minicolors jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-minicolors

In [jquery-minicolors](https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/), input box by its nature, display the color and color code in hex as demostrated in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dotmartin/edkg6jmr/5/).

I tried to find a possible solution that the text box of `minicolors` display the color swatch and the color name instead of color hex code.

[image]

The result of below code does not work for me. Any clue and tip I can achieve that? Thanks.

```js
// Hide all stuffs
$('.rw_widget_colour').addClass('rw_hidden');

// Init minicolors
$('.text').minicolors();

// Set color
$('.colorpicker').minicolors('value', '#2ed1c1');

// Show
$('.rw_widget_colour').removeClass('rw_hidden');

$.minicolors.defaults.theme = 'bootstrap';
$('input').minicolors({
  control: 'brightness',
  swatches:['#031b4d','#303e4d','#062847','#00122e','#115478','#243447','#152324','#11202f'],
  show: function() {
    $('.minicolors-grid,.minicolors-slider').css('display','none');
    $('.minicolors-swatches').css('margin-top','10px');
  },
  change: function(value, opacity) {
    var ColorName = {
                  '#031b4d':'Blue',
                  '#303e4d':'Black',
                  '#062847':'Orange',
                  '#00122e':'Pink',
                  '#115478':'Green',
                  '#243447':'Red',
                  '#152324':'Gray',
                  '#11202f':'Dark Gray'
                };
    console.log(value+':'+ColorName[value]);                
    $(this).val(ColorName[value]);
  }
})
```

```css
.rw_hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.css">
<script src="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.js"></script>    


<form class="aui">
    <label class="rw_widget_colour">
        <div class="rw_widget_swatch">jaoja</div>
        <input class="text colorpicker" type="text" name="rw_widget_colour" value="#ff0"/>
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: so where is your code in the fiddle?

Comment: you may take a look to [Name that Color](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/#6195ED)

Comment: @gaetanoM, thanks, the name of color and is hex code was already defined in `ColorName` but `$(this).val(ColorName[value]);` did not display the name and color does not show up in textbox.

Comment: let me take a look

Comment: @gaetanoM, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the js lib [Name that Color](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/#6195ED) you can get the color name like this:

```
ntc.name(value)
```

The snippet:

```js
$('.rw_widget_colour').addClass('rw_hidden');
$('.text').minicolors({
    change: function(value, opacity) {
        var n_match  = ntc.name(value);
        $('.rw_widget_swatch').text(n_match[1]);
    }
});
$('.colorpicker').minicolors('value', '#2ed1c1');
$('.rw_widget_colour').removeClass('rw_hidden');
```

```css
.rw_hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.css">
<script src="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/insomnious0x01/ntc-js/master/ntc.js"></script>

<form class="aui">
    <label class="rw_widget_colour">
        <div class="rw_widget_swatch">jaoja</div>
        <input class="text colorpicker" type="text" name="rw_widget_colour" value="#ff0"/>
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, how is the value when form submitted, color name or hex code? I would want to display color name and store value in color hex code.

Comment: @HouyNarun I suggest to use an hidden input field and use that on your server side. Let me know

Comment: I will have a look at “name that color” library and test your answer, if it work actually, I will let you know and mark as accepted. Thanks very much :)

Comment: I have tried it and it did not work as I wish. I have limited color for user just those defined in `ColorName`, its value and its name. I want, when any one of those color selected, its name display next to the color and store a color code as defined in `ColorName`. Only those color that I limit for my user. Thanks.